# Get coordinates from title in Mapbox GL JS

Tags: javascript, mapbox-gl-js

Is it possible to get a marker/point's coordinates, based on it's title?

I'm, loading in several points, which all have specific IDs as their title. 
What i need now, is the ability to flyTo one of these markers when i enter the view and one is highlighted.
I'm highlighting with the below function, and would like to implement the flyTo in it.

```
$scope.$on('$ionicView.afterEnter', function(){ 
    if(ShowOnMap.story()){
        var storyId = ShowOnMap.story();
        map.setFilter("highlight", ["==", "title", storyId]);
        map.flyTo({
            center: [---->storyId<-----],
            zoom: 18
        });
        ShowOnMap.setStory(false);
    }
});
```

So all i need, is a way to get the position(coordinates) of the point, based on the ID/Title i receive.

Bonus info: The storyID is sent from another view, and i am currently not able to send the coordinates and would like to avoid requesting the coordinates from server, based on ID.